# LiveZilla - Doesn't work with SSL?

Tags: nginx, centos, php-fpm

I am running a CentOS server with NGINX and PHP-FPM, everything runs with SSL. I also use cloudflare.

I tried installing [LiveZilla](https://www.livezilla.net/home/en/) to a subfolder called `livezilla/`.
Upon visiting `/livezilla` in my browser, I see this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mhJB.jpg

There should be a big blue button in the middle stating something along the lines of `Install Now`, which is not the case here. I also get errors in the browser console:

```
(index):126 Uncaught ReferenceError: install_goto is not defined
    at HTMLTableRowElement.onclick ((index):126)
onclick @ (index):126
index.js:66 Uncaught ReferenceError: lz_update_mode is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.js:66)
    at j (jquery-2.1.0.min.js:2)
    at Object.add [as done] (jquery-2.1.0.min.js:2)
    at o.fn.init.o.fn.ready (jquery-2.1.0.min.js:2)
    at index.js:58
```

I tried to open the website with `http://` instead of `https://` and it initially redirected me back to `https://`, but after adding a Page Rule in cloudflare where I disabled SSL, RocketLauncher and Security it worked. I installed LiveZilla and everything seemed to work, the floating chat button appears on my website and I can even use the data pass-through to pass usernames to the operator console.

BUT when I try to send a message in the chat, it doesn't work. It says `connecting...` forever and the server never receives the message.

What I tried:

- Reinstalling livezilla (New subfolder, new database)
- All combinations of the following Server settings: Server refuses all connections without encryption (HTTP), Use HTTPS? -> Always, Detect automatically
- Creating chat buttons for http and https.

So what could be the culprit here? I really don't know why LiveZilla does not load with https. Any nginx configuration maybe?

Comment: What did they say when you contacted them?

Comment: They haven't answered my ticket yet, unfortunately. I also signed up for the forums, but I am still not allowed to start a new topic.